# Navigating & Passing Data Between Pages Ionic 2

Tags: json, ionic2

I'm having some issues while navigating between pages with Ionic2.

I have a List of Data, that I got from a data.json

*Here is the list*

[image]

I want to get details:

Example - From "A"

The data that I have on my data/Example.Json

```
 {
  "title": "A",
  "lat": 2.323733,
  "lon": 64,546465
},
```

So as soon as I click on the Title, I want to get the title, lat and lon on a new page.

app.modules.ts

```
    import { NgModule, ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicModule, IonicErrorHandler } from 'ionic-angular';
import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { MapPage } from '../pages/map/map';
import { ListPage } from '../pages/list/list';
import { DetailPage } from '../pages/detail/detail';
import { Locations } from '../providers/locations';
import { GoogleMaps } from '../providers/google-maps';
import { Connectivity } from '../providers/connectivity';
declare var google: any;

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    MapPage,
    ListPage,
    DetailPage
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    MapPage,
    ListPage,
    DetailPage
  ],
  providers: [{provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},Locations,GoogleMaps, Connectivity]
})
export class AppModule {}

    import { NgModule, ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicModule, IonicErrorHandler } from 'ionic-angular';
import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { MapPage } from '../pages/map/map';
import { ListPage } from '../pages/list/list';
import { DetailPage } from '../pages/detail/detail';
import { Locations } from '../providers/locations';
import { GoogleMaps } from '../providers/google-maps';
import { Connectivity } from '../providers/connectivity';
declare var google: any;

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    MapPage,
    ListPage,
    DetailPage
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    MapPage,
    ListPage,
    DetailPage
  ],
  providers: [{provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},Locations,GoogleMaps, Connectivity]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

PageA.ts ( list of Data )

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Locations } from '../../providers/locations';
import { DetailPage } from '../detail/detail';


@Component({
  selector: 'page-list',
  templateUrl: 'list.html'
})
export class ListPage {


  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public locations: Locations) {

  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('Test Si marche');


  }

  viewLocation(event,location) {
    this.navCtrl.push(DetailPage, {
      "title":location.title,
      "longitude":location.longitude
    })
  }

}
```

Page B ( where i want to get the detail as soon as i click on something on the list )

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import {NavParams} from "ionic-angular";
import { Locations} from '../../providers/locations';
import { ListPage } from '../list/list';





@Component({
    selector: 'page-detail',
    templateUrl: 'detail.html',
    providers: [ Locations ],
    entryComponents:[ ListPage ]
})


export class DetailPage {

    title: string
    latitude: string
    navParams: NavParams

    constructor(navParams: NavParams,public navCtrl: NavController) {
        this.navParams = navParams
        this.title = this.navParams.get('title');
        this.latitude = this.navParams.get('latitude');
    }

    ionViewDidLoad(err) {
        console.log(err);


    }
    goBack() {
        this.navCtrl.pop();
    }

}
```

listA.html

```
 <ion-header>

    <ion-navbar color="secondary">
        <ion-title>List</ion-title>
    </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>


<ion-content>

    <ion-list no-lines>

        <ion-item *ngFor="let location of locations.data">

            <ion-item (click)="viewLocation($event, locations)">{{locations.title}}</ion-item>
            <ion-avatar item-left>
                <ion-icon name="pin"></ion-icon>
            </ion-avatar>
            <!--<img src="./src/pics/mus.png"/>-->
            <h2>{{location.title}}</h2>
            <p>{{location.distance*1.609}} Km</p>
        </ion-item>

    </ion-list>

</ion-content>
```

data.json

```
  [
  { "title": "Cat", "longitude": "14,57" },
  { "title": "Bird", "longitude": "17.45" },
  { "title": "Spider", "longitude": "19,12" }
]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? You should show the code you have (relevant to this problem), and tell us how it's not working.

Comment: @Schlaus as an exemple :



  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

    this.list = [
      { Name: 'A', lat: 154564, lng:2.454},

    
  }

  public Listitem(l)
  {
    this.navCtrl.push(DetailsPage,{item:l});

  }

}

My problem that i have my list on a different file stored on data.json i want to get it from there and display the details

Comment: So, you want to get the data from a different file and then send it as a param during Navigation..?

Comment: @RajaYogan Yes sir !!! I have a list :

*A
*B
*C

As soon as i click on A i get the details of A ( Title + lat + lon ) which is stored on a Data.json

Comment: Well, if the data in the list doesn't change, then you could simply use a lifecycle event trigger namely ionViewDidEnter() to load the data pertaining to title A in the pageB.ts file

In pageB.ts

constructor() {}

ionViewDidEnter() {
//load data from your file
}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to pass data from one page to another, you can either

1) Store your JSON data in SQL format via JSON.stringify(store) and JSON.parse(retrieving) method.

Meaning you stringify the data, before storing inside the SQL table and once retrieved from the next page, you do a JSON.parse to get back your JSON object.

You may want to read up on the following article on how to store data in SQL.
[SQL Ionic 2](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2016/08/using-sqlstorage-instead-sqlite-ionic-2-app/)

[JSON Parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

[JSON Stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

Or either which, 2) you can make use of navController to "push" data from one page to another. One downside would be if your JSON data is huge, you will have to slowly iterate through.

A simple example would be:

```
this.navController.push(ThePageNameYouWannaGo, {
      firstPassed: "firstData",
      secondPassed: "secondData",
      thirdPassed: "thirdData",
});


//On the next page (at your constructor),

Constructor(....,NavParams,.....){

  this.first = navParams.get("firstPassed");
  this.second= navParams.get("secondPassed");
  this.third= navParams.get("thirdPassed");

//the value would be stored inside this.first, this.second respectively
```

For your case, I would recommend method 1 as I have no clue how big is your JSON file and to make your life easier in the future when your JSON file changes.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, i got this error : Cannot read property 'parameters' of undefined at ReflectionCapabilities.parameters

Comment: @Taieb which method are u using?

Comment: I manage to correct it now when i want to display the detail on page B , i get a blank page i did console.log(this.title); ==>nothing

Comment: if you are printing console in your other methods, try add in this line: " var self = this; console.log(self.title); "

Comment: this.navParams = navParams
    this.title = this.navParams.get('title');
  this.latitude = this.navParams.get('latitude');

are undefined it's on my PageB , going to edit the topic, so you can check the code

Comment: this.navParams = navParams "U forget to end it with a ;"

Comment: this.title = this.navParams.get('title'); U dont need to declare "this.navParams" again, using "this.title = navParams.get('title');" should suffice

Comment: U might not even need this line of code "this.navParams = navParams;"

Comment: change it ! now i got this caused by: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined


@Gene thank you for all your patience

Comment: get of undefined meaning navParams.get("firstPassed"); , meaning your navParams may or may not be initialized properly .

Comment: Here is the code : constructor(navParams: NavParams,public navCtrl: NavController) {

    this.title = this.navParams.get('title'); 
  
    this.latitude = this.navParams.get('latitude');

    
    }

Comment: this.title = navParams.get('title'); this.latitude = navParams.get('latitude');  -> try.

Comment: see this link: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavParams/

Comment: Tried all things + the link you gave me, always blank :/ Here is the error (http://i.imgur.com/CH2NUXc.png)

Comment: I think somewhere u might missed out something. See the official documents and try to follow. I would had helped but mine is using an older version of ionic 2 thus, I cant replicate your problem. Sorry about that