# Ionic 2 Navigating & Passing Data Between Pages

Tags: json, ionic2

I'm having some issues while navigating between pages with Ionic2.

I have a List of Data, that I got from a data.json

*Here is the list*

[image]

I want to get details:

Example - From "A"

The data that I have on my data/Example.Json

```
 {
  "title": "A",
  "lat": 2.323733,
  "lon": 64,546465
},
```

So as soon as I click on the Title, I want to get the title, lat and lon on a new page.

app.modules.ts

```
    import { NgModule, ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicModule, IonicErrorHandler } from 'ionic-angular';
import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { MapPage } from '../pages/map/map';
import { ListPage } from '../pages/list/list';
import { DetailPage } from '../pages/detail/detail';
import { Locations } from '../providers/locations';
import { GoogleMaps } from '../providers/google-maps';
import { Connectivity } from '../providers/connectivity';
declare var google: any;

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    MapPage,
    ListPage,
    DetailPage
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    MapPage,
    ListPage,
    DetailPage
  ],
  providers: [{provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},Locations,GoogleMaps, Connectivity]
})
export class AppModule {}

    import { NgModule, ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicModule, IonicErrorHandler } from 'ionic-angular';
import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { MapPage } from '../pages/map/map';
import { ListPage } from '../pages/list/list';
import { DetailPage } from '../pages/detail/detail';
import { Locations } from '../providers/locations';
import { GoogleMaps } from '../providers/google-maps';
import { Connectivity } from '../providers/connectivity';
declare var google: any;

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    MapPage,
    ListPage,
    DetailPage
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    MapPage,
    ListPage,
    DetailPage
  ],
  providers: [{provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},Locations,GoogleMaps, Connectivity]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

PageA.ts ( list of Data )

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Locations } from '../../providers/locations';
import { DetailPage } from '../detail/detail';


@Component({
  selector: 'page-list',
  templateUrl: 'list.html'
})
export class ListPage {


  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public locations: Locations) {

  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('Test Si marche');


  }

  viewLocation(event,location) {
    this.navCtrl.push(DetailPage, {
      "title":location.title,
      "longitude":location.longitude
    })
  }

}
```

Page B ( where i want to get the detail as soon as i click on something on the list )

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import {NavParams} from "ionic-angular";
import { Locations} from '../../providers/locations';
import { ListPage } from '../list/list';





@Component({
    selector: 'page-detail',
    templateUrl: 'detail.html',
    providers: [ Locations ],
    entryComponents:[ ListPage ]
})


export class DetailPage {

    title: string
    latitude: string
    navParams: NavParams

    constructor(navParams: NavParams,public navCtrl: NavController) {
        this.navParams = navParams
        this.title = this.navParams.get('locations').title;
        this.latitude = this.navParams.get('locations').latitude;
    }

    ionViewDidLoad(err) {
        console.log(err);


    }
    goBack() {
        this.navCtrl.pop();
    }

}
```

listA.html

```
 <ion-header>

    <ion-navbar color="secondary">
        <ion-title>List</ion-title>
    </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>


<ion-content>

    <ion-list no-lines>

        <ion-item *ngFor="let location of locations.data">

            <ion-item (click)="viewLocation($event, locations)">{{locations.title}}</ion-item>
            <ion-avatar item-left>
                <ion-icon name="pin"></ion-icon>
            </ion-avatar>
            <!--<img src="./src/pics/mus.png"/>-->
            <h2>{{location.title}}</h2>
            <p>{{location.distance*1.609}} Km</p>
        </ion-item>

    </ion-list>

</ion-content>
```

data.json

```
  [
  { "title": "Cat", "longitude": "14,57" },
  { "title": "Bird", "longitude": "17.45" },
  { "title": "Spider", "longitude": "19,12" }
]
```

So I got this Error : **Cannot read property 'parameters' of undefined at ReflectionCapabilities.parameters**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Navigating & Passing Data Between Pages Ionic 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43172892/navigating-passing-data-between-pages-ionic-2)

Comment: This question has been answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36780195/how-to-pass-data-in-ionic2)

Comment: @murhaf sousli, this one is more detailed i followed the steps but got the error at the end.

Comment: `<ion-item (click)="viewLocation($event, locations)">{{locations.title}}</ion-item>` Are you sure about this line? I think for this line all the `locations` should be `location`

Comment: Changed it to : <ion-header>

    <ion-navbar color="secondary">
        <ion-title>Detail</ion-title>
    </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>


<ion-content>

    <ion-list no-lines>

     


            <ion-avatar item-left>
              
            </ion-avatar>

            <h2>{{title}}</h2>

         


    </ion-list>

</ion-content>

Got a blank page :/

Answer (score 0):

Please change the code in PAGE B 
from
(YOUR CODE)

```
 constructor(navParams: NavParams,public navCtrl: NavController) {
        this.navParams = navParams
        this.title = this.navParams.get('locations').title;
        this.latitude = this.navParams.get('locations').latitude;
    }
```

to (MY CODE)

```
constructor(navParams: NavParams,public navCtrl: NavController) {
    this.navParams = navParams
    this.title = this.navParams.get('title');
    this.latitude = this.navParams.get('longitude');
```

Comment: I Got Cannot read property 'title' of undefined 

Here is my PageB.html

`<ion-header>

    <ion-navbar color="secondary">
        <ion-title>Detail</ion-title>
    </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>


<ion-content>

    <ion-list no-lines>

     


            <ion-avatar item-left>
              
            </ion-avatar>

            <h2>{{location.title}}</h2>
         


    </ion-list>

</ion-content>`

Comment: its not location.title, its just title in PAGE B

Comment: Change it i got a blank page.

Comment: then the data is not passed to the PAGE B from PAGE A, Try console.log() at every point to see where the data is missing